# How to pull out text within an h3 tag class in selenium using python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I currently am having difficulty extracting text from the following page:

[image]

I have tried `browser.find_element_by_class_name("W6bZuc.YMllz").text`

and also

`browser.find_element_by_tag_name("h3").text`

but these all come up empty. Is there a way to get the `h3` element consistently using selenium webdriver in python? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting `textContent`

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("W6bZuc.YMllz").get_attribute("textContent")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use `.get_attribute('innerHTML')`:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.W6bZuc.YMllz').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```